# Dynamically adding nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to dynamically add values in a nested dictionary. I am trying to cache similarity score of two words with their part-of-speech-tag.

In short I want to store values as this;
    `synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2][word2_tag] = score`

```
class MyClass(Object):

    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.synset_cache={} #dict

    def set_cache(self,word1, word1_tag, word2, word2_tag, score)
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1]={} #create new dict
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag]={} #create new dict
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2]={} #create new dict
        #store the value
        MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2][word2_tag] = score
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Type error: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Line number it shows is at `MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag]={} #create new dict`.

How can I get this working?

**EDIT:**
According to the @Robᵩ's comments on his answer; I was assigning a list to this `MyClass.synset_cache` in another method(note it is at the class-level). So this code part had no errors.

Comment: who ever down voted? may i know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict.setdefault`.

This might work:

```
#UNTESTED
d = MyClass.synset_cache.setdefault(word1, {})
d = d.setdefault(word1_tag, {})
d = d.setdefault(word2, {})
d[word2_tag] = score
```

Alternatively, you can use this handy recursive defaultdict that springs up new levels of dict automatically. (See: [here](http://recursive-labs.com/blog/2012/05/31/one-line-python-tree-explained/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250).)

```
import collections
def tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(tree)

class MyClass(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.synset_cache=tree()

    def set_cache(self,word1, word1_tag, word2, word2_tag, score)
        MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2][word2_tag] = score
```

Comment: getting AttributeError: list object has no attribute `setdefault` at `d = d.setdefault(word1_tag, {})`.

Comment: Then you have some code outside of what you've shown us that is doing something like `MyClass.synset_cache[word1] = []`. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste that entire short program into your original question.

Comment: Oops. i think i found the problem. you are right! I was using same var in another method and assigning a list to it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Oftentimes, in reducing a broken program to the shortest possible reproducible test case, a person discovers the problem on their own. The lesson to learn is this: **always** provide a complete test case when asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This will be data dependent, as at least for some test data (see below), the code does not produce that error. How are you calling it?

Also, note that as written above, it won't compile due to some syntax errors (i.e. no colon to end the `def set_cache` line).

Below is some tweaked-to-compile code with some example calling data and how that pretty-prints:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.synset_cache={} #dict

    def set_cache(self,word1, word1_tag, word2, word2_tag, score):
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1]={} #create new dict
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag]={} #create new dict
        try:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2]
        except:
            MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2]={} #create new dict
        #store the value
        MyClass.synset_cache[word1][word1_tag][word2][word2_tag] = score


x = MyClass()

x.set_cache('foo', 'foo-tag', 'bar', 'bar-tag', 100)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

pp.pprint(x.synset_cache)
```

Which outputs:

```
{   'foo': {   'foo-tag': {   'bar': {   'bar-tag': 100}}}}
```

A couple other things of note...

I'd recommend using the `in` style syntax to check for key presence rather than `try`-`except`. It's more compact and more Pythonic.

Also, your main variable, `synset_cache`, is class-level (i.e. static). Did you mean for that to be the case?

Comment: Sorry, the code part, i pasted here had no error. As @Rob pointed out I was assigning a list on this same var in another method by mistaken.

Comment: I am using  multiple threads and calculating similarity is expensive. so I decided to cache it at class-level and use `threading.Lock()`.

Comment: Ah. I'd still recommend switching to the `in` style key-checking syntax, though (not that it makes a functional difference, just for the reasons I mentioned above).